# When calculating for the absorption coefficient of material, why are my Sabine equation calculations off by a factor of 100?

Tags: acoustics

For my school physics research report, I am conducting an investigation into the different factors that affect the "absorption coefficient" of materials. 
For this, I am using the Sabine equation which I have found to be:

> $$_\color{grey}{\text{reverberation time s}}\ T=\frac{0.161\times \overbrace{V}^\color{grey}{\text{room volume m$^3$}}}{\Sigma(\underbrace{S}_\color{grey}{\text{area of surface m$^2$}}\times\underbrace{\alpha}_\color{grey}{\text{absorption coefficient}})}$$

$$RT(60) = \frac{55.25 \times V}{\Sigma(\text{Surface area of a wall} \times \text{walls absorption coefficient})}$$

For the reverberation time of $RT(60)$ in my designated space, I measured the drop in the sound level to 30 decibels, and as some sites that I have looked at say that sound level decay is linear, I multiplied $RT(30)$ with $2$ to equal $RT(60)$.

Furthermore, as all container walls were made of the same material, I simply factored out the absorption coefficient from the sum:

$$\begin{align}
\Sigma(S\times\alpha) &= (S_1\alpha_1)+(S_2\alpha_2)+(S_3\alpha_3)+\cdots \\
&= \alpha(S_1+S_2+S_3+\cdots)
\end{align}$$

and after some rearranging, I was left with $$\alpha = \frac{(.161)(V)}{(RT(30)\times 2)(S)}$$

Using this equation, the value for wood, for example, should be something like $0.2$, and I calculated $0.208$, so that works out.

However, I did the calculations with $\mathrm{cm}^3$ and $\mathrm{cm}^2$, using the cm dimensions of my space ($40\mathrm{cm} \times 40\mathrm{cm} \times 59.7\mathrm{cm}$). After I realized this mistake, I used meters, but this time it gave me $0.002$, which is 100 times off what it should be.

I am unsure why there is a $10^{-2}$ error in my calculations, and my teacher could not help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the given equation in terms of the physical quantities involved, we find:
$$[Time]=\frac{[Length]^3}{[Length]^2 \times[\text{Units of a}]}$$It follows that $$[\text{Units of a}]=[Velocity]$$

So that changing the units of length from centimetres to metres will cause a reduction in the numerical value of a by a factor of $100$.

Comment: I see, so if I were to divide the resultant [Unit of a] by say the speed of sound, I would get a value of x 10^-2 anyway. I did not see that before thanks! But can be done, or rather what is the mistake that causes the x 10^-2 in the first place?

Comment: The only mistake you made was to ignore the units of your answers:  you obtained 0.208 cm/s the first time, and 0.00208 m/s the second time,  These results are the same...